# Dataflow from Colab issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a Dataflow job from Colab and getting the following worker error:

```
sdk_worker_main.py: error: argument --flexrs_goal: invalid choice: '/root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-1dbd101c-a79e-432e-89b3-5ba68df104d7.json' (choose from 'COST_OPTIMIZED', 'SPEED_OPTIMIZED')
```

I haven't provided the `flexrs_goal` argument, and if I do it doesn't fix this issue. Here are my pipeline options:

```
beam_options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project=...,
    job_name=...,
    temp_location=...,
    subnetwork='regions/us-west1/subnetworks/default',
    region='us-west1'
)
```

My pipeline is very simple, it's just:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
  (pipeline 
    | beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
        query=f'SELECT column FROM {BQ_TABLE} LIMIT 100')
    | beam.Map(print))
```

It looks like the command line args for the sdk worker are getting polluted by jupyter somehow. I've rolled back to the past two apache-beam library versions and it hasn't helped. I *could* move over to Vertex Workbench but I've invested a lot in this Colab notebook (plus I like the easy sharing) and I'd rather not migrate.

Comment: I've just tried this on Vertex Workbench and getting the same error, and that's with their beam specialized kernel. Strange.

Comment: Hi @Will, can you clarify your use case and also provide the sample code that you have tried ?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. The `PipelineOptions` constructor will pull in `sys.argv` if no parameter is given for the first argument (called `flags`). In my case it was pulling in the command line args that my jupyter notebook was started with and passing them as Beam options to the workers.

I fixed my issue by doing this:

```
beam_options = PipelineOptions(
    flags=[],
    ...
)
```